# How can I impute missing values using a yearly growth rate in python?

Tags: python, pandas, imputation

I have a dataset in the following format:

```py
            Country Code    Year    Value
        0   ABC     32      2000    NaN
        1   ABC     32      2001    NaN
        2   ABC     32      2002    NaN
        3   ABC     32      2003    NaN
        4   ABC     32      2004    1000000.0
        5   ABC     32      2005    NaN
        6   ABC     32      2006    NaN
        7   ABC     32      2007    NaN
        8   ABC     32      2008    NaN
        9   ABC     32      2009    NaN
```

and I am trying to replace the NaN values in such a way that they show yearly growth of r% around the non-NaN value; in other words, for the example data, Value[i] should be equal to 1000000 * (1+r)^x where x is the difference between the index of the non-NaN value and the index of i.

For this small set, the following code does the job:

```py
df['imputed'] = ''
gr = 0.05 # growth rate

for i in range(len(df)):
    nx = df.Value.first_valid_index() # index of first non-NaN value
    nv = df.Value[df.Value.first_valid_index()] # first non-NaN value
    df['imputed'][i] = nv * (1+gr) ** (i - nx)
df


    Country   Code      Year    Value       imputed
0   ABC       32        2000    NaN         822702
1   ABC       32        2001    NaN         863838
2   ABC       32        2002    NaN         907029
3   ABC       32        2003    NaN         952381
4   ABC       32        2004    1000000.0   1e+06
5   ABC       32        2005    NaN         1.05e+06
6   ABC       32        2006    NaN         1.1025e+06
7   ABC       32        2007    NaN         1.15763e+06
8   ABC       32        2008    NaN         1.21551e+06
9   ABC       32        2009    NaN         1.27628e+06
```

However, the real dataset has multiple combinations of 'Country' and 'Code' which require similar calculations (NOTE: each of these combinations has only one non-NaN value just like above).

If I make a new df (df2) with all of the required Country-Code combinations, how could I apply the above calculations to every matching combination in the main df? Please note that there are also many combinations which do not require such calculations.

```py
df2
    Country Code
0   ABC     32
1   DEF     27
2   GHI     19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process just a filtered dataframe from the whole data with respect to the country or anything, then you can append or merge all together. I just present the method here. Feel free to play around with the code below, and tailor it for a more opitimized solution.

**Code:**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
df2['Country'] = np.array([(c*10).split() for c in ['ABC ', 'DEF ', 'GHI ']]).ravel()
df2['Code'] = np.array([(c*10).split() for c in ['32 ' , '27 ', '19 ']]).ravel()
df2['Year'] = np.arange(2000,2010).tolist() * 3
df2['Value'] = np.nan
df2.loc[[4,14,24],'Value'] = [1000000.0, 2000000.0, 3000000.0]

# print(df2)
df2.drop('id', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.Value = df.Value.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == 'NaN' else float(x))

df2['imputed'] = 0
def process(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        nx = df.Value.first_valid_index() # index of first non-NaN value
        nv = df.Value.loc[nx] # first non-NaN value
        # print(nv,gr,i,nx)
        df.loc[i,'imputed'] = nv * ((1+gr) ** (i - nx))
    return df


new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df2.Country.unique():
    cond = (df2.Country == c)
    p_df = df2[cond].copy()
    p_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    df_ = process(p_df)
    new_df = new_df.append(df_, ignore_index=True)

print(new_df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Country Code  Year      Value       imputed
0      ABC   32  2000        NaN  8.227025e+05
1      ABC   32  2001        NaN  8.638376e+05
2      ABC   32  2002        NaN  9.070295e+05
3      ABC   32  2003        NaN  9.523810e+05
4      ABC   32  2004  1000000.0  1.000000e+06
5      ABC   32  2005        NaN  1.050000e+06
6      ABC   32  2006        NaN  1.102500e+06
7      ABC   32  2007        NaN  1.157625e+06
8      ABC   32  2008        NaN  1.215506e+06
9      ABC   32  2009        NaN  1.276282e+06
10     DEF   27  2000        NaN  1.645405e+06
11     DEF   27  2001        NaN  1.727675e+06
12     DEF   27  2002        NaN  1.814059e+06
13     DEF   27  2003        NaN  1.904762e+06
14     DEF   27  2004  2000000.0  2.000000e+06
15     DEF   27  2005        NaN  2.100000e+06
16     DEF   27  2006        NaN  2.205000e+06
17     DEF   27  2007        NaN  2.315250e+06
18     DEF   27  2008        NaN  2.431013e+06
19     DEF   27  2009        NaN  2.552563e+06
20     GHI   19  2000        NaN  2.468107e+06
21     GHI   19  2001        NaN  2.591513e+06
22     GHI   19  2002        NaN  2.721088e+06
23     GHI   19  2003        NaN  2.857143e+06
24     GHI   19  2004  3000000.0  3.000000e+06
25     GHI   19  2005        NaN  3.150000e+06
26     GHI   19  2006        NaN  3.307500e+06
27     GHI   19  2007        NaN  3.472875e+06
28     GHI   19  2008        NaN  3.646519e+06
29     GHI   19  2009        NaN  3.828845e+06
```

Comment: hmmm, why not [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)?

Comment: I just gone straidforward, for the solution, I intend to make it more general. You are right, this can be achieved with groupby and with proper function which would be more suitable. I stated in the answer to play around with the code to get more optimized solution for his case though.